# Latest Pycharm version: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'constant'

Tags: tensorflow, pycharm

I am newbie on machine learning, want to have a try on tensorflow.
My IDE is Pycharm, used to work in past.
But after I update to latest version which released on July 25th, it could not identify tensorflow lib properly. Even I tried about basic function.

```
import tensorflow as tf
node = tf.constant(4.0)
print(node)
```

Raising error like:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'constant'
```

Here is my project interpreter i used:
[project interpreter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBCrB.jpg)

Could anyone help?

Comment: Do you have a file `tensorflow.py` in same directory?

Comment: @aristotll you are right, I made a very stupid name on my file.Thank you very much for figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a very horrible decision on my file name. After I changed it back, everything working

Comment: can you please elaborate what you did, i am facing the same problem, but i did not made any changes such horrible !